# SQL Server SUM GROUP BY Help

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I have a table that contains an `orderid`, an `inventoryid`, and a `quantity` -- its a line items table. The database is SQL Server 2008.

What I need to know is how to write a SQL statement that returns the sums of quantities for that `itemid` at that order, not counting orders that have larger `orderids` than it. It must return the `orderid`, `itemid`, and `total`.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something, but if you are summing quantities of items for an order, what does other orders with larger orderids have anything to do with it?  Wouldn't they be excluded since they're not part of the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess:

```
SELECT
    SUM(quantity) AS total, --"sums of quantities for that itemid at that order"
    orderid, inventoryid --"It must return the orderid, itemid"
WHERE
    orderid < (some larger order id value) --"not counting orders that have larger orderids"
GROUP BY
    orderid, inventoryid
```